# Only 2 USB hard drives recognized when 3 connected in Windows 7

Tags: windows, usb-storage

I've got 3 hard drives (with power supply, USB 2.0 and 3.0). They are all recognized by Windows7 x64 when they're plugged in individually, or when 2 of them are plugged in at the same time (on any of my 4 laptop's USB ports).

However, when the 3 of them are plugged in at the same, W7 only detects the 2 first ones plugged in.

I also tried to plug them on a hub (which has a power supply) and it gives the same result.

When the 3 of them are plugged in at the same time and there's 1 or more pen drives plugged in, only 2 hard drives are recognized but all the pen drives are recognized as well...

Anyone might have a clue why that's happening?

Comment: this is more of a super user question. but i would guess that the third is underpowered.

Comment: All three are powered?

Comment: definitely not power supply, it was just an "a signature collision with another disk": other usefull link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprohardware/thread/4ba1cff4-3b3f-4c05-931b-a8be875d96fe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This question would definitely have been better on superuser.com.  Live and learn :)

2) This link has two good suggestions:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-7-not-recognizing-two-usb-external-hard/740fcde9-b000-4c49-9a43-c0926b37feb7

a) power supply

```
 ... and/or ...
```

b) Manually enable the (third) drive in Disk Mgr (where it *might* be visible, to enable)